# Can `lucene 5.0.0`'s SmartChineseAnalyzer specify or add my custom dictionary?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

The `cnsmart` chinese analyzer of lucene performs well.
In specific domain, though, I need to expand its dictionary.
I wonder whether `cnsmart` can support adding a custom dictionary or replacing the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SmartChineseAnalyzer` remains experimental, and I don't see a good way to specify where to pull in a custom dictionary.  There are some hooks for it, if you take a look in the `AnalyzerProfile`, and *it seems like* you should be able to load a custom dictionary via an "analysis.data.dir" system property.  From the source:

```
// Try the system property：-Danalysis.data.dir=/path/to/analysis-data
ANALYSIS_DATA_DIR = System.getProperty("analysis.data.dir", "");
```

However, looking at the `WordDictionary` source, this looks like it is (still) going to only be loaded if the embedded dictionary fails to load.  Since it is embedded in the jar, it generally would not be expected to ever fail.

Considering all that, probably the easiest way to use your own dictionary will be to grab the `lucene-analyzers-smartcn-5.0.0.jar`, extract it, replace `org/apache/lucene/analysis/cn/smart/hhmm/coredict.mem` with your dictionary, and rebuild the jar.

See [LUCENE-1817 : it is impossible to use a custom dictionary for SmartChineseAnalyzer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1817) for some discussion on this.  Rather old, but again, looking at the source, it looks like everything said there still applies.

All of this is assuming your dictionary is in a format that is readable by the analyzer.  There is a `bigramdict.mem` alongside `coredict.mem` in the jar, presumably an expanded dictionary not in standard use due to performance concerns, so that might be worth trying as well.

Comment: Do you know how to generate own dictionary with the format which is same as `coredict.mem`?

Comment: No, afraid I can't help you there.  It's from [ICTCLAS1.0](http://sewm.pku.edu.cn/QA/reference/ICTCLAS/FreeICTCLAS/English.html).  To the best of my knowledge, if you were thinking to just add a few words, you'll find it's [not that simple](http://www.programdevelop.com/5139661/).